# problem when uninstalling a package

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, mysql

```
root @ OF01-LT-IT-2026: ~ # sudo apt remove
Reading list of packages ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading the status information ... Done
The following packages will be DELETED:
  mysql-connector-python
0 updated, 0 new will be installed, 1 to delete and 143 not updated.
1 not installed at all or deleted.
638 kB will be released after this operation.
do you wish to continue? [S / n] s
(Reading the database ... 185416 files or directories currently installed.)
Uninstalling mysql-connector-python (2.1.4-1ubuntu12.04) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
dpkg: error processing the mysql-connector-python (--remove) package:
 installed mysql-connector-python package post-removal script the thread returned an error with exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-connector-python
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
root @ OF01-LT-IT-2026: ~ #
```

Comment: Please use `sudo env LC_ALL=C apt remove`  so we can get English output.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
 dpkg: error processing the mysql-connector-python (--remove) package: installed mysql-connector-python package post-removal script the thread returned an error with exit status 1 Errors were encountered while processing: mysql-connector-python E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1

Answer (score 0):

**Se necesita mas detalle**

Algo que vi que tal vez te ayude es que entraste `sudo apt remove` sin dar el nombre del paquete/programacion/biblioteca que quieres remover. Cual es el proposito de lo que haces? Si quieres eliminar paquetes que ya no sirven, usa `sudo apt autoremove`. Por favor, clarifica tu cuestion...

**Si el paquete este roto**

Hay un articulo aqui que se trata de o reparar o remover paquetes rotos aqui:
[How to remove an incomplete package by using apt-get? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455626/how-to-remove-an-incomplete-package-by-using-apt-get). Aunque se trata de usar `apt-get` en vez de `apt`, la informacion se puede usar a tu favor...

---

**Needs more detail**

Something that I saw is that you entered `sudo apt remove` without giving the name of the package/program/library you want to remove. What is it exactly that you are trying to accomplish here? If you want to remove packages that don't work anymore, use `sudo apt autoremove`. Please clarify the situation.

**If the package is broken**

There is an article here that talks about repairing or removing broken packages here: [How to remove an incomplete package by using apt-get? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455626/how-to-remove-an-incomplete-package-by-using-apt-get). Even though it uses `apt-get` instead of `apt`, this information is still pretty useful.

Comment: +1 thank you but I did not work this other method, the package can not be removed,

   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'

dpkg: error processing the mysql-connector-python (--remove) package:

  installed mysql-connector-python package post-removal script the thread

returned an error with exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

  mysql-connector-python

E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)